# Error: Duplicated files or mocks. ReactNative-Expo-sanity.io

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, expo, sanity

so have been developing a react native app using Expo and sanity.io as back-end, when I implemented sanity as backend i started getting an error just on the mobile versions(ios simulator, and andorid studio), but the web version is still working fine.

Error i have been getting in the mobile versions

[image: 1]

Android studio error

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

The cause for me was that I had two different `package.json` files with the same value for the name property.

So if you go into your sanity sub folder and change the `name:` field inside of `package.json` to something different than the one in your main directory everything should work fine.